# Unable to Raise Views On UWP Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am currently unable to raise the child views in my layout for UWP but it works for android. (same code just change the image source) Any kind soul can help me out with this?

The code below should display 2 images and 2 buttons. the images overlap each other as I am testing whether the image will get successfully raised. On android, it works perfectly fine but on UWP it does not and I am not sure what I  might have missed out as PCL is supposed to be common so by right the code should work on both platforms.

Below is my code:

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UWPRaiseTest"
             x:Class="UWPRaiseTest.MainPage">

    <ContentView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Violet" x:Name="EntireLayout" IsEnabled="True">
        <RelativeLayout x:Name="ImageHolder" IsEnabled="True">
                <Image x:Name="Img1" Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" IsEnabled="True"
                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0,Constant=100}"
                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0, Constant=0}" />
                <Image x:Name="Img2" Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png" BackgroundColor="Red" IsEnabled="True"
                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0,Constant=120}"
                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0, Constant=0}" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <Button x:Name="RaiseObj1" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" Text="Raise image 1 " Clicked="RaiseObj1_OnClicked"  />

            <Button x:Name="RaiseObj2" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" Text="Raise image 2" Clicked="RaiseObj2_OnClicked"/>

        </StackLayout>
</ContentView>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace UWPRaiseTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void RaiseObj1_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ImageHolder.RaiseChild(Img1);
            ImageHolder.LowerChild(Img2);

            EntireLayout.RaiseChild(Img1);
        }

        private void RaiseObj2_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ImageHolder.RaiseChild(Img2);
            EntireLayout.RaiseChild(Img2);
            ImageHolder.LowerChild(Img1);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the 2.4.0 prerelease builds. You can refer to the originally filed bug [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38770).